# Yii form: Uploading multiple files at once?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, widget, yii

I need to upload multiple file at once with the YII form.
I tried the CMultiFileUpload widget, but the problem with it, you can't choose multiple file at once.
Any idea how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an yii extension called [xupload](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/xupload/) that makes use of [jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).
There is also a good [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/348/xupload-workflow/) to getting started on implement the extension.

With some changes I got it working in my application.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading multiple files at once, i always use plupload (http://www.plupload.com/). Theres a simple wrapper/extensions to handle plupload in yii here http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pupload/

I've used it in many projects, works fairly well.

Comment: There isn't an easier way? because I can't manage to get the post data, and the action in the controller is never called. I tried also muploadify, and blueimp but they are tricky to setup.